# Getting ROBOT_CONTINUE_ON_FAILURE = true to work

Tags: python, robotframework

I would like to set ROBOT_CONTINUE_ON_FAILURE variable from test framework python libraries. But, it doesn't seem to work at all.

This is what I'm doing -

```
class TestCaseFailedException(Exception):
    ROBOT_CONTINUE_ON_FAILURE = True
```

Are there any imports that I need while setting this variable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one library named 'A.py'

```
from robot.errors import RemoteError
class A(object):
    def fun(self,var):
        if int(var)>5:
            raise RemoteError('test','test',fatal=True,continuable=True)
```

one test named ''

```
*** Test Cases ***
test
  Fun  10
  Log  111
```

self.ROBOT_EXIT_ON_FAILURE = fatal

self.ROBOT_CONTINUE_ON_FAILURE = continuable

when fatal is 'True', no matter what continuable is,the test will  exit at step 'Fun 10'.
But if  fatal is 'False' and the continuable is 'True',the test will run finished.

Comment: I'm getting - TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fatal'

Comment: For example:                                                   from  robot.errors import RobotError
class YourError(RobotError):
    """some words."""

    def __init__(self, message='', details='', fatal=False, continuable=False):
        RobotError.__init__(self, message, details)
        self.ROBOT_EXIT_ON_FAILURE = fatal
        self.ROBOT_CONTINUE_ON_FAILURE = continuable